# Java - Displaying directory contents based on search using recursion

Tags: java, search, recursion, directory

My task is to write a class RFind which recursively searches the current directory and its subdirectories, attempting to match files against its single regular expression argument.

So far the only thing I have tried is the following which a) isn't recursive and b) doesn't really seem to work. How would you go about doing this?

NB: The sample solution given displays how you could pass regex in the command line and how it would look:

**$ java RFind ".*.java"**

**./RFind.java**

**./src/AHTNF.java**

**$**

```
public class RFind {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a regular expression: ");
        String regex = in.next();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

        File dir = new File (".");

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(files[i].toString());
            if (m.matches()) {
                f.add(files[i].toString());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(f.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For there to be *any* attempt at recursion, you first must write a method in addition to your main method. Think what parameters this method should receive and what it should return (if anything). This will help you get over 50% of the way towards your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be recursive you need at least one method to be called

```
public class Rec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a regular expression: ");
        String regex = in.next();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

        new Rec (p).start (".");
    }

    private Pattern p;

    Rec (Pattern pP)
    {
       p = pP;
    }

    void start (String pDir) {
        File dir = new File (pDir);

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files == null) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            String x = files[i].toString();
            if (".".equals(x)) continue;
            if ("..".equals(x)) continue;

            Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            if (files[i].isDirectory ()) {
               start (pDir+File.separator + x);
            }
        }
    }
```

May run, not compiled yet

Comment: @m92: we know it too which is why both stefan and myself suggest you start by trying to create the skeleton of this method. It doesn't have to be correct, but it does have to be tried. To stefan: shouldn't this be a comment not an answer(see my comment made 2 min before your answer above) since this does not "answer" the question?

Comment: It needs some time, but it is an answer

Comment: @stefanbachert You shouldn't give out answers to other peoples homework.